# How to use find in unix excluding folders and files with size condition?

Tags: unix, find, solaris

Working on Solaris 10 in ksh:

I'm trying look after big files on all my root disk but I need to exclude some folders and files.

Currently the ksh find command doesn't succeed:

```
find / -type d \( ! -name NFS* ! -name proc ! -name devices \) -type f \( ! -name /backup_DB0/databases/data/ems_data.dat ! -name /backup_DB1/databases/log/ems_log.dat \) size +1000000 -exec ls -lah {} \;
```

This example is shortened, the files list is about 20 files, is there a limit to the command?

Answer (score 2):

As @peterh hinted at, your question is about usage of the `find` command, and the only impact your choice of shell would have is likely on how you escape potentially special characters like `(` and `!`.

Your `find` command uses [a grammar](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/find-1.html#scrolltoc) that you're not quite using properly. You're close, though.

Just as with English, if you want to express multiple conditions, you need a logical construct that joins them, like "or" or "and". (See what I did there?) The `find` command concatenates conditions with an implicit "and" by default, and uses `-o` to designate a logical "or".  For example:

`find $path`*`condition1`*`! \\(`*`condition2`*`-o`*`condition3`*`\\)`

specifies that condition1 must be true, but the entire expression is false if either condition2 or condition3 is true.

In your case, if I'm understanding your conditions properly, I would suggest constructing your expression more like this:

```
find / \( -type d ! \( -name NFS\* -o -name proc -o name devices \) \) \
    -o \( -type f ! \( -name ems_data.dat -o -name ems_log.dat \) \) \
    -size +1000000 \
    -ls
```

With this, I've separated your "ANDed" expressions onto separate lines, and the "or" expressions are showing inside nested brackets.

*Note: remember that **-size** is in blocks long (512 bytes per block). Check the man page for how to specify size in bytes.*

As to your last question about a limit, you certainly shouldn't have a problem with 20 files. If you were dealing with thousands of files, I'd be worried that you'd reach a limit set by your operating system, noted in `ARG_MAX` from `/usr/include/limits.h`. To determine your particular limit, if you have a C compiler installed, you may be able to run the following:

```
$ cpp <<HERE | tail -1
#include <limits.h>
ARG_MAX
HERE
```

My systems all tell me that 262144 characters is the limit. Note that this limit is imposed by the OS's attempt at POSIX compliance, so it *should* be the same regardless of which shell you're using.

Comment: @Zion, you're very welcome. Please feel free to click the green checkmark beside the answer to "close" this question, if you feel it covers everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

When the list of files to exclude can change often, you might want to exlude them with a sort of config file.

```
# cat /dontfind
/backup_DB0/databases/data/ems_data.dat
/backup_DB1/databases/log/ems_log.dat
# find ... | grep -vf /dontfind | xargs ls -l
```